# Ubuntu 15.04 postgresql doesn't start

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cloud-init

I have a cloud-init script that works on Ubuntu 14.04 when I launch an AWS instance:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux
exec > >(tee /var/log/bootstrap.log)
exec 2>&1
apt-get --quiet --quiet update
apt-get --quiet --quiet upgrade
apt-get install --quiet --quiet postgresql
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'foo';"
```

Now I want to pick up Ubuntu 15.04, but suddenly the service does not start properly, and my `CREATE USER` command fails:

```
+ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD '\''foo'\'';'
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I can do this from command prompt, indeed I can do it after the cloud-init scripts runs by stopping and starting the service, so I do not understand what the problem could be.

I have tested with

- http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-9e0aa4e9--ubuntu-images-hvm-io1-ubuntu-utopic-14-10-amd64-server-20141022-3 - this works
- http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-ecde819b--ubuntu-images-hvm-io1-ubuntu-vivid-15-04-amd64-server-20150818 - does not.

Help, please.

Comment: What happens when you start postgres. Not sure what the equivilent of the command for ubuntu is: `sudo service potsgresql start` or `/etc/init.d/postgresql start`

Comment: Is the PostgreSQL service running? Anything you can find in the system/database logfile?

Comment: No, the service is not running, `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log` is empty, and `/var/log/syslog` has nothing interesting in it.

Comment: Once the instance is up and cloud-init has finished I can do `sudo service postgresql stop` + `sudo service postgresql start`, after which my `sudo -u postgres psql -c 'CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD '\''foo'\'';'` just works.
So I have tried do that as part of the cloud-init script (padded with appropriate calls to sleep, pstree and inspecting status), but that does not work either.
So it seems there is something fishy about running this in the context of cloud-init.

Comment: Update: I raised a bug and added a workaround for now:

`pg_ctlcluster --force 9.4 main stop || true`
`pg_ctlcluster --force 9.4 main start || true`

Comment: I had the exact same issue, thanks for the work around